# printSchema having all columns in the first one

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have loaded a text file using the `load` csv function but when I try to print the schema it shows just one field from the root including every row in that one. like this:

```
root
 |-- Prscrbr_Geo_Lvl    Prscrbr_Geo_Cd  Prscrbr_Geo_Desc    Brnd_Name
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is the csv file actually using tab characters to separate different columns? If so, you should do something like `spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", "\t").load("/path/to/file")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer since it seems to have solved the problem.

From the output, it looks like the CSV file is actually using tab characters as the separator between columns instead of commas. To get Spark to use tabs as the separator, you can use `spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", "\t").load("/path/to/file")`

Answer (score 0):

df2 = spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", "\t").option("header",True).option("infraschema",True).load("/home/ranga/Downloads/spark _docs/interview_preparation/data1.csv")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).